# Pydantic: Validate discriminated union with literals

Tags: python, discriminated-union, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to use `Literal` to create a discriminated union with Pydantic.
There are events about a Job resource, and I want to distinguish them by `event_name`. For `JobPublishedEvents` I want to ensure, that some `extra_field` is present.

```py
class GenericJobEvent(BaseModel):
    event_name: str
    id: int


class JobPublishedEvent(GenericJobEvent):
    event_name: Literal['job.published']
    extra_field: str


class Wrapper(BaseModel):
    wrapped: Union[JobPublishedEvent, GenericJobEvent]

print(type(Wrapper(wrapped={'event_name': 'some.event', 'id': 1}).wrapped))  # GenericJobEvent
print(type(Wrapper(wrapped={'event_name': 'job.published', 'id': 1, 'extra_field': 'extra'}).wrapped))  # JobPublishedEvent
print(type(Wrapper(wrapped={'event_name': 'job.published', 'id': 1}).wrapped))  # GenericJobEvent
```

The first 2 cases behave as expected, for the third I would like a validation error since the literal matches, but the schema is not fulfilled. I get why the fallback to the GenericJobEvent is valid, though.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that while `JobPublishedEvent` fails, `GenericJobEvent` does not. Think about it, the `event_name` attribute is a string, the `id` is an int. Everything matches.

So, what you could do, is to validate also the `event_name` in `GenericJobEvent` and reject the event name `job.published`

You can validate it as explained in the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)

```
@validator('event_name')
    def event_name_filter(cls, v):
        if 'job.published' == v:
            raise ValueError('GenericJobEvent cannot have event_name equal to job.published')
        return v.title()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with "I get why the fallback to the GenericJobEvent is valid". What I would need is for the GenericEvent to accept all strings except the ones defined in subclasses... Thank you for your solution!

Comment: Sorry, too much multitasking led to distracting me. Glad I've helped